# What is it useful for to have class type attributes in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, class

I have inherited a software in C++. The software contains below given code
which is hard for understanding to me.

DeviceAlarms.h

```
class DeviceAlarms {

public:
     
    class DetectedAlarms {
        AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_A alarm001;
        AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_B alarm002;
        AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_C alarm003;
        AlarmOVERVOLTAGE         alarm004;
        AlarmOVERTEMPERATURE     alarm005;
    } detectedAlarms; 

};
```

Alarms.h

```
class AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_A{
    bool evaluateAlarmCondition(ControlBlocks *ctrl) {
      return ctl->currentSensorPhaseA->getCurrent() > PHASE_A_OVERCURRENT_LEVEL;
    }
};

class AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_B{
    bool evaluateAlarmCondition(ControlBlocks *ctrl) {
      return ctl->currentSensorPhaseB->getCurrent() > PHASE_B_OVERCURRENT_LEVEL;
    }
};

class AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_C{
    bool evaluateAlarmCondition(ControlBlocks *ctrl) {
      return ctl->currentSensorPhaseC->getCurrent() > PHASE_C_OVERCURRENT_LEVEL;
    }
};

class AlarmOVERVOLTAGE{
    bool evaluateAlarmCondition(ControlBlocks *ctrl) {
      return ctl->voltageSensorDcLink->getVoltage() > DC_LINK_OVERVOLTAGE_LEVEL;
    }
};

class AlarmOVERTEMPERATURE{
    bool evaluateAlarmCondition(ControlBlocks *ctrl) {
      return ctl->temperatureSensorHeatSink->getTemperature() > HEATSINK_OVERTEMPERATURE_LEVEL;
    }
};
```

I think that it means that there is a class `DeviceAlarms` which has one public attribute
called `detectedAlarms` of `DetectedAlarms` class type. The `detectedAlarms` attribute is
a "container" containing private elements called `alarm001` - `alarm005`. I have following
questions:

1. What is it usefull for to have class type elements alarm001 - alarm005 in the detectedAlarms
   container? I am able to understand a situation when I have pointers to those classes in a container
   but class types only doesn't make any sense for me.
2. How will be created the instances of classes `AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_A`, `AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_B`,
   `AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_C`, `AlarmOVERVOLTAGE`, `AlarmOVERTEMPERATURE`?

Please can anybody help me to understand my code? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

1. The code is intended to run on a microcontroller i.e. some C++ features are prohibited.
2. All the alarm classes have a common base class which I have omitted because I thought that it it not important for my question.

Comment: who wrote that code? Typically you would ask the author first rather than random guys on the internet why code was written the way it was written. I agree, it doesnt make sense

Comment: how it's used?.

Comment: This is very poorly written code. Author should have used functions/lambdas/function objects, but for some unknown reason he used unrelated classes. 1. None. Better approach would be to have vector/array of objects/functions. 2. These classes essentially empty, so there is nothing to create. But if you wonder, they will be created in constructor of `DeviceAlarms`.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I have just edited my question to partly answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
class DeviceAlarms {

public:
     
    class DetectedAlarms {
        AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_A alarm001;
        AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_B alarm002;
        AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_C alarm003;
        AlarmOVERVOLTAGE         alarm004;
        AlarmOVERTEMPERATURE     alarm005;
    } detectedAlarms; 

};
```

Is mostly equivalent to:

```
class DetectedAlarms {
    AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_A alarm001;
    AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_B alarm002;
    AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_C alarm003;
    AlarmOVERVOLTAGE         alarm004;
    AlarmOVERTEMPERATURE     alarm005;
}; 

class DeviceAlarms {

public:
     
    DetectedAlarms detectedAlarms; 

};
```

Other than the fact of where exactly the `DetectedAlarms` declaration lives - which isn't necessarily all that relevant if this is the only usage of it.

For a consumer of `DeviceAlarms` in either case they could use it such as:

```
DeviceAlarms da;
da.detectedAlarms.alarm001.evaluateAlarmCondition(x);
```

On the other hand the original author could have done:

```
class DeviceAlarms {

public:
     
    AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_A alarm001;
    AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_B alarm002;
    AlarmOVERCURRENT_PHASE_C alarm003;
    AlarmOVERVOLTAGE         alarm004;
    AlarmOVERTEMPERATURE     alarm005;

};
```

Which would lead to usage like:

```
DeviceAlarms da;
da.alarm001.evaluateAlarmCondition(x);
```

So given only what we can see of this code, to me it just looks like the original author wanted to have that extra `.detectedAlarms` in there, perhaps because they thought it might be clearer. Although if `DeviceAlarms` is used in more places or instances are passed around, then perhaps there is more justification of it being a convenient way to package multiple alarms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as of instantiation of the individual alarm classes as they are mentioned in the DeviceAlarms or in the detectedAlarms. This is done by the implicit constructor of the DeviceAlarms class?

Comment: @L3sek Yeah, they're instantiated as typical for any members.